# How to make a website "phone aware"?

Tags: web, css, html5, phone

So here's the deal; I've got a website fully coded in desktop and phone versions, but I don't know how to make the website *know* that the device visiting the site is either a desktop computer or a mobile device, so it loads either version of the site accordingly. How can I do that? I'm still pretty much a novice in web development so I don't know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How have you built the phone version? [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com)? Generally you go off screen size to make the guess at the site to display.

Comment: Yes it's using bootstrap

Comment: The easy way to test the site is to grab the edge of your browser and shrink it

Comment: Programming questions should be asked on [so].

Answer (score 1):

This solution doesn't require javascript and work very well through desktop, tablet and smartphones. You will have one single file for every page making easy to do changes, upgrades, etc.

First of all you will need this on the `head` section on every `html` file:

`<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>`

Then, in the CSS file you can make a responsive design able to adapt to different screen sizes. For example on your css file you define:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
    color: #636770;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("/images/bg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

#top {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:40px;
    height: 147px;
    position: static;
}

@media (max-width:800px){


    #top {
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        margin-top:5px;
        position: static;
    }
}
```

In this example we have defined `body` as a general element with the same properties for every screen size, but `#top` is defined in a way that on desktop will have a top margin of 40 px, and when the *screen width* is below *800px* the top margin is 5px.

Answer (score 1):

You state you are using Bootstrap to build your website, because of this you shouldn't have two versions. You build a single version then specify the elements to show at various screen sizes with CSS classes.

The Bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries) on how to use the grid system is helpful in this case.

To test the site you can either shrink the size of your browser and the elements will reorder, resize or disappear depending on the breakpoints you have set or you can use a service like [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com) which emulates various browsers.